# Make multiple checks for empty variables less verbose/lengthy

Tags: php

I found myself quite often checking if multiple variables are empty. In some case it can lead to ugly code. I feel like its possible to make it shorter. But none of my solution seems best-practice.

Task: Lets throw an exception when encounter empty value.

```
$x = 1;
$y = "foo";
$z = 3;
$q = 0;
$p = null;

//this can get too lengthy
if (empty($x) || empty($y) || empty($z) || empty($q) || empty($p)) {
    throw new \Exception("Empty value");
}
```

The best solution I was able to do is with arrays. But I personally found it ugly.

```
foreach ([$x, $y, $z, $q, $p] as $value) {
    if (empty($value)) {
        throw new \Exception("Empty value");
    }
}
```

I end up with sort of global function to have in one line when checking:

```
function has_empty_element(array $subject)
{
    foreach ($subject as $value) {
        if (empty($value)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

if (has_empty_element([$x, $y, $z, $q, $p])) {
    throw new \Exception("Empty value");
}
```

Is there any way to make it one-line without extra function? Could be my "array approach" be considered as good? Thank you.

Comment: Is it always numbers or can it be strings/book too?

Comment: @Andreas any values are possible (string, instances etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I believe your foreach is a good method.
I'm not saying this is a better method but I'm giving you an option.

If you count the variables (in an array) and compare against an array_filter of the same you will see if one or more is empty.

Most likely this is slower than your foreach but at least it can be in one line.

```
if(count([$x, $y, $z, $q, $p]) !=  array_filter([$x, $y, $z, $q, $p])){
    echo "empty variables";
}
```